# Unsure why returning array is empty

Tags: java, json, ldap

I have a problem with an array being returned empty, and am not sure where is the problem.

On click of the provided link with the person name, using angularjs, the name that was clicked on is sent as a parameter to a java class named APPservlet.java in which this code is then ran.

```
case "personName": {
        try {
            ldapAuthenticationServiceAccess.getADPersonInfo(session.getAttribute("personName").toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
        }
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        tmpJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            PersonADInfo info = new PersonADInfo();

            tmpJSONObject = new JSONObject();
            tmpJSONObject.put("name", info.getName());
            tmpJSONObject.put("email", info.getEmail());
            tmpJSONObject.put("sector", info.getSector());
            tmpJSONObject.put("workplace", info.getWorkplace());
            jsonArray.put(tmpJSONObject);

            jsonObject.put("person", jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
            log.error(e);
        }

        writer.println(jsonObject.toString());

    }
        break;
```

When that java class is called, within it, the method getADPersonInfo(String) is called, which is located inside of the java class LDAPAuthenticationServiceAccess.java and it's purpose is to connect to LDAP and then to the AD to get the user's info. That info is then passed to a class called PersonADInfo.java which contains getters and setters. Here is the code.

```
    public void getADPersonInfo(String username) {      

    String returnedAttributePerson[] = {"distinguishedName", "givenName" , "sAMAccountName" };

    String searchFilterPerson = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=" + username + "))";
    String searchBasePerson = "DC=Something,DC=local";

    SearchControls searchCtlsPerson = new SearchControls();
    searchCtlsPerson.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    searchCtlsPerson.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttributePerson);
    LdapContext ctxGCPERSON = null;
    try {
    ctxGCPERSON = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    NamingEnumeration<?> answerPERSON = ctxGCPERSON.search(searchBasePerson, searchFilterPerson,
            searchCtlsPerson);

    while (answerPERSON.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult srPERSON = (SearchResult) answerPERSON.next();
        Attributes attrsPERSON = srPERSON.getAttributes();
        PersonADInfo personADInfo = new PersonADInfo();
        personADInfo.setName(username);
        personADInfo.setEmail(attrsPERSON.get("distinguishedName").get().toString());
        personADInfo.setSector(attrsPERSON.get("givenName").get().toString());
        personADInfo.setWorkplace(attrsPERSON.get("sAMAccountName").get().toString());

    }
} catch (NamingException e) {
    log.error(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The variables that are being set are just for testing purpose only and are set only to see if anything will return. For now, the only thing that returns is an empty array and i'm not sure where is the problem, this kind of project is a first for me so i beg your understanding, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Note: this project uses SSO and therefore each time i test it i need to upload a war file to a remote tomcat server.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are facing. `jsonObject` is empty because it only contains `jsonArray`, which is an empty object too.

Comment: I just edited the code, i saw that exact mistake. Still doesn't work as expected.